# How to import a macro file (previously exported as .bas file) to Microsoft Word using command line?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I'm writing a command-line program that has a step in which I need to replace text in a Word file. The replacing task is accomplished using Word macro.

What I need to do now is to call this macro from command-line. At the moment we can do this by using the `/mMacroName` parameter of 'winword.exe', i.e. `<path-to-msoffice>\winword.exe /mMacroName`. But this needs the macro to be already available as a global macro.

Since I need to run the program on another computer, I need to import the above replacing macro programmatically... and I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the macro using VBScript would be an option. You can find a sample to get started in the following related question:

> [Remove MS Word macro using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342526/remove-ms-word-macro-using-vbscript)